# AngularJs UnitTesting $httpBackend Give No Pending Request To Flush

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

## Here is my test  code, and always get the error message above.

```
'use strict';
describe('getmodules', function () {
window.__env.platform = 'jasmine'; // web || mobile || desktop
beforeEach(function () { module('myApp', 'ngMockE2E', 'ngCookies'); });
var service, $httpBackend, defaultAlertFactory, $cookies, $http;
var $controller;
var $rootScope;

beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    service = $injector.get('dashboardService');
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    $http = $injector.get('$http');
}));

it("should return a list of getmodules", function () {
    debugger;
    var result1 = null;

    $httpBackend.when('GET', '/home/modulesInfo').respond(true, ['david', 'James', 'Sam']);

    /* Code Under Test */
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/home/modulesInfo'
    }).then(function (success,response) {
        result1 =response;
    }, function (error) {

    });
    $httpBackend.flush();
    expect(result1).toEqual(["david", "James", "Sam"]);

});
```

});

========================================================
Not sure why? have the $http.get(), and use the flush() to call the fack httpBackend call, should be good. still not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your thenable function syntax as like below:

And check out this working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/l9GglRbnTkmC8EG9yJBL?p=preview)

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/home/modulesInfo'
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(response.data));
  result1 = response.data;
}, function(error) {

});
```

Comment: actually, it is the "ngMockE2E" issue, after remove it, and works. anyway thanks for your plunker example.